# "next" and "previous" buttons won't work in this touch slider plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins, slider

I am using touchSlider plugin: http://www.mobilizetoday.com/freebies/touchslider/examples#ex-6

I integrated this exact part of the plugin in my website(which I am making responsive). the sliding with the finger works perfectly, but the buttons aren't working. Here is my website: http://dev.ux-pm.com. To get the page where the slider is, just decrease browser width to less than 480px, and click on `level 1 in detail` (blue button)

HTML code:

```
<div class="gallery-holder">
            <div class="gallery" id="gallery3">
                <div class="holder">
                    <div class="list">
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="ibox">
                                level1
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="ibox">
                                level2
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="ibox">
                                level3
                             </div>
                         </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="prev">Prev item</a>
                <a href="#" class="next">Next Item</a>
                <span id="counter"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

                    $('#gallery3').touchSlider({
                        mode: 'index',
                        center: true,
                        prevLink: 'a.prev',
                        nextLink: 'a.next',
                        onChange: function(prev, curr) {
                            $('#counter').html((curr+1)+'/'+ $('#gallery3').get(0).getCount());
                        },
                        onStart: function(){
                            $('#counter').html('1/' + $('#gallery3').get(0).getCount());
                        }
                    });
    });
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    font: 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #666;
    max-width: 800px;
    min-width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h1, h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #333;
}

.box {
    width: 96px;
    height: 96px;
    line-height: 96px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 2px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.box img {
    width: 96px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.box1 {background: red;}
.box2 {background: blue;}
.box3 {background: orange;}

.ibox,
.cbox,
.fbox {
    width: 210px;
    height: 210px;
    line-height: 210px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 2px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.centered .ibox,
.centered .cbox{
    margin: 2px auto;
    padding: 0 2px;
}


.ibox img {
    width: 210px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.cbox img,
.fbox img{
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.fbox {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    line-height: 600px;
}

span.delta {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 1px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: magenta;
}

.ibox span.delta {
    height: 210px;
}

.active .box {
    outline: 1px dashed green;
}

.gallery-holder {
    margin: 0 auto;
    outline: 1px dashed #666;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

.gallery {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery div.holder {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery div.list {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 9999px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery div.item {
    float: left;
}

/*.moving {
    background: yellow;
}*/

.debug-item {
    padding: 1px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    color: #999;
    font-size: 11px;
}

#menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu a {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 6px 0;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #333;
    background: #EFEFEF;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}

a.prev,
a.next,
#moveTo,
a.tablink,
#counter {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #333;
    background: #EFEFEF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.prev {float: left;}
a.next {float: right;}

#moveTo,
#counter {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}

.focus .ibox {
    outline: 1px dashed green;
}
.focus-old .ibox {
    outline: 1px dashed red;
}

#tabs, #tabs2 {
    text-align: center;
}
.tablink {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 2px;
}
a.active {
    border-color: #333;
}

#tabs2 .tablink {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}

#tabs2 a.active {
    background-color: #666;
}
```

I have desperately tried to find the problem, but I couldn't .. Any help? thanks

Comment: I don't see your JS script above on the actual page. Also, you have jQuery loaded twice, which often causes issues.

Comment: Ralph it's weird that my js is loaded twice, I have looked everywhere for a place where I could have loaded it twice! any idea why it is loading twice?

Comment: I'm not very experienced with WP, but it may be that one or more add-ons is throwing it in there by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You navigation elements aren't nested inside of `gallery3`, which is where the plugin expects them to be:

```
<div id="left2">
<div class="gallery-holder">
        <div class="gallery" id="gallery3">
            <div class="holder">
                <div class="list" style="transition: 0.5s ease; -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease; -webkit-transform: translate3d(60px, 0px, 0px);">
                    <div class="item active"></div>
                    <div class="item"></div>
                    <div class="item"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<a href="#" class="prev">Prev item</a>
<a href="#" class="next">Next Item</a>
<span id="counter">1/3</span>
```

The touchSlide plugin looks within the initialized objects scope for the button selectors. http://touchslider.com/

Try nesting them in side of `gallery3` but not inside of `holder`.

Comment: lemieuxster since you already know this plugin, I am having another problem, the slider swipes perfectly on ios, but VERY bad on other devices like nexus 4 and 5, samsung, and probably other devices.(they were supporting chrome, this could be the problem). Yet it is working perfectly when I decrease the width of my desktop browser! I have no idea why it's happening. any idea? you can see a link to the website in my question up. you could just jump to the section "training program" to see it.

Comment: @user3618369 I am not sure why there would be a difference, except in how the plugin is using the browser events and in how those are fired. Actually, looking at the code it appears to only use touch events on browsers it things are webkit, so maybe the detection isn't working correctly. In any case I'm afraid I can't be of much more help for now.